# Statsmodels cannot import module

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to use the `statsmodels.discrete.conditional_models.ConditionalLogit` class in statsmodel.

when importing the module in jupyter notebook, the conditional_models file is not found in discrete:

```
import statsmodels as sm
sm.__version__
dir(sm.discrete)
```

Results:

```
['PytestTester',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'count_model',
 'discrete_margins',
 'discrete_model',
 'test']
```

```
sm.discrete.conditional_models.ConditionalLogit
```

Result:

> AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.discrete' has no attribute 'conditional_models'

However, when I looked in the actual directory of statsmodels.discrete locally, I found the conditional_models.py file in the directory.

Installation : by pip version : '0.12.0.dev0+10.ge9ca9ca55'

Answer (score 2):

Try importing it this way (see the [statsmodels docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api-structure.html#direct-import-for-programs) on their example for importing classes and functions):

```py
from statsmodels.discrete.conditional_models import ConditionalLogit
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I faced an error like this, it was because of my statsmodels version so it was resolved just by a simple uninstall/install.

```
pip uninstall statsmodels 
pip install statsmodels
```

If you find the file it could installed but no properly so the action should do the trick.

Comment: sadly i tried that multiple times with both pip and conda, but the result was the same, also tried version 0.11 :((((

Comment: Try to create a virtual env then with only the packages you need. Check also for python version compatibility with statsmodels